# Transferring of the value between activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my project I have such situation, that one activity should transfer the value to another. And depending of this value should be chosen needable menu element. I tried to do it with the help of `bundle`, but I don't know how to choose the needable element of menu. Can I access to menu item with the help of this number or I can access only with the help of the id?

Comment: You can send over the ID as it is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already now, you can start another activity with `Intent` which also allows you to transfer some small amounts of data like `String` or `Integer` (which you need) with `.putExtra()` property.

So, for your problem you will do something like this:

`public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";`

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
 int menuOption = 1; // or whichever menu option you want
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, menuOption);
 startActivity(intent);`

In another activity, you will read that value like this:

`Intent intent = getIntent();
 String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`

You can read all about [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java) in official Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- if you are using activity you can pass the data on click using intent like this

  ```
  create_new_bank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(BankDetailsActivity.this, AddBankDetailsActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("id",id);
          intent.putExtra("bank_Name", bankname);
          intent.putExtra("holder_name", holdername);
          intent.putExtra("acc_no", accountno);
          startActivity(intent);
  ```
- and get the data next activity **eg (AddBankDetailsActivity.this)** like this:

  ```
  /* using get string intent method  get intent value*/
  private void getStringIntent() {
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String bank_id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
  String accountName = intent.getStringExtra("holder_name");
  String accountNo = intent.getStringExtra("acc_no");
  String bankName= intent.getStringExtra("bank_Name");
  ```

**Note:**  make sure your putExtra key value same in getStringExtra key value

it helps you